# domain connecting to localhost and links not working (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: wordpress, hosting, website, localhost, linked-server

I'm having trouble to get my website properly online, which I created/designed in Wordpress.

I have bought a domain and rented a WordPress hosting server. I have uploaded my whole WordPress folder on my server by FileZilla and have as well uploaded my local database over `phpMyAdmin` to my new database which i got from my hosting provider (Strato). But when ever I'm searching my domain my computer is directly connecting with WordPress on localhost. Which I don't understand why, because I have uploaded my database on the `phpMyAdmin` account of my host. Shouldn't it then open the domain directly?

When I'm opening a `inkognito` tab in chrome my website does open, but none of my links are working and an error appears that says **This site can't be reached localhost refused to connect**. Why does it try to connect with localhost and what can I do that the sites are opening?

As well its weird the font on my total website changed by itself, it isn't the one I have chosen and the color have changed also by itself. Does anyone know why this all is happening and what can I do so that everything is shown correctly?

PS: in WordPress everything works and looks the way it should but online not!

Comment: Within phpmyadmin and select your database. When the tables appear select wp_options where you will find two fields which need to be modified. Change the value of the "siteurl" and "home" fields to reflect your new domain name. That might not fix it but it's a very good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

When moving a website from your development environment to a production server you need to ensure the Site URL and Home variables reflect your new URL.

You are using phpmyadmin which is excellent for making changes in your database when your front end or dashboard are not working.

**What is happening now**

When you initially installed Wordpress, in your development environment, you have most likely told Wordpress that it is located at "localhost". This value is used by Wordpress to construct its URLS, retrieve themes & styles. When moving to another URL, Wordpress will continue trying to get what it needs from "localhost" rather than your new domain.

**Edit the database**

Open phpmyadmin and select your database. The database will load and all the Wordpress tables will be shown.

You will need to change the "options" table which is likely to be called wp_options or similar. Open the table and modify these two fields;

1. siteurl
2. home

Change the value from whatever it was to your new domain name, including http or https such as http://example.com or http://example.com/wordpress if your site is located in a sub folder.

Save the changes and attempt to reload your website. Clear any browser caches if necessary.

**It should be working now**